# How to detect if an outgoing call is answered in Android 13?

Tags: calls, bugs, aosp, vanilla-android, android-13

On Motorola Edge 30, the system setting for this is not working. Interestingly, I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/x13a/Vibe/issues/6) that suggests this might be a bug in Android 13.

Is there a workaround or a reliable way to detect specifically when an outgoing call is answered in Android 13?

Comment: @Andrew, why the rollback?

Comment: After investigation, the editor was found to be abusing an unacceptable tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using UI Automator

```
pip install uiautomator2
```

```
ip = 'ZD22276G7K'
# ip = '192.168.1.247'
import uiautomator2 as u2
from pymsgbox import alert
from time import sleep
d= u2.connect(ip)
ele = d(resourceId="com.google.android.dialer:id/contactgrid_status_text")
try:
    while True:
        et = ele.get_text()
        if et != 'Calling…':
            alert('Calling')
            break
        print(et)
        sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    alert('Error')
```